# Sum power series not continuous unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, power-series, hardy-spaces

This is (probably) not a research question and I already asked [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694252/sum-power-series-not-continuous-unit-circle) on StackExchange but I got no answer over there.

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{\geq 1} = \left(\frac{\cos(2\sqrt{2n}+\frac{\pi}{4})}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ and the associated power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n z^n$. It is easily checked that the radius of convergence of this series is $1$. Furthermore, one can prove this power series converge also on the unit circle (I give a sketch of a proof at the end of the question). Let me denote by $F$ the sum of the power series on the unit disk.

**Question :** Is the function $F$ continuous on the unit circle?

The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291914/find-an-example-of-a-sequence-not-in-l1-satisfying-certain-boundedness-condit/1291988#1291988) and the comments below seem to imply that $F(z) = exp\left(-\frac{1+z}{1-z} \right) + G(z)$, where $G$ is a continuous function on the unit disk. Hence $F$ should be not continuous in $1$. The arguments given there seem to me however rather difficult and roundabout (asymptotic estimations of the Laguerre polynomials, computations with Maple, etc).

**More precise version of the question** : Is there a relatively direct and simple proof that $F$ is not continuous on the unit circle?

I should also mention that the behaviour of $F$ on the unit circle is also studied in Zygmund's *Trigonometric series* (around page 200). He gets some estimates like $F\left(e^{ix} \right) =_{0^{-}} O\left( \log|x| \right)$. This is rather interesting and suggests that something special is happening when $z=1$, but the big $O$ is too crude and doesn't allow to conclude that $F$ is not continuous in $1$.

**Appendix** Let me sketch an argument that the power series converges on the unit circle. To make notations cleaner I will prove that the power series asociated to $\frac{\cos(\sqrt{n})}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ converges on the unit circle (the proof is the same for both sequences). Note that it is then sufficient to prove that the power series associated to the sequence $(b_n)_{\geq 1} = \left(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{n}}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ converges on the unit circle. Let $z_0 = e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{U}$.

$\bullet$ If $z_0 = 1$. One must prove that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n}}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ is convergent. But an easy computation shows that:
$$ \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n}}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}} = -2i.\left(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{n+1}} - e^{i\sqrt{n}} }{n^{\frac{1}{4}}} \right) + c_n,$$
where $c_n$ is the general term of an absolutely convergent series. The Abel's test then implies that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n}}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ is convergent.

$\bullet$ If $z_0 \neq 1$. One must prove that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n}+ i n\theta}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ is convergent. The same computation as before shows:
$$ \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n} +in \theta}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}} =  \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-1}.\left(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{n+1} + i(n+1)\theta} - e^{i\sqrt{n} +in \theta} }{n^{\frac{3}{4}}} \right) + d_n,$$
where $d_n$ is the general term of an absolutely convergent series. The Abel's test again implies that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{n} + in \theta}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ is convergent.

Comment: if you look at the expression $\sum_{ M \le k \le 2M}e^{i\sqrt k +ik\theta}$ you notice that for $\theta=0$ you can estimate it by $O(\sqrt M)$ by the usual techniques, but for $\theta$ near $0$ for example around $-1/(2\sqrt M)$ say, the estimate fails and only a $M^{3/4}$ can be obtained, so indeed the convergence looks non-uniform there hence a discontinuity is plausible;

Comment: @Conrad : thanks for your comment. The estimations you mention are exactly the ones I highlight in the appendix to the question.

Comment: IMO this question is very appropriate for MO.